# numpy randint() to generate bytes

Tags: python, numpy, oop

I have to make a stream cipher that takes in input a byte generator (`randint` function by default). I tried to implement it in this way but I don't want to have at the output the `str(`) representation, I want the bytes one, so `b'\x.......')`.

I read that `bytes()` with a list of integers gives the `str` representation, so if I return `crypted` in the `crypting_fn`, with a `for` cycle to pass to the `bytes()` only one `int` at a time, will I solve my "problem"? If not, can you please explain to me how can I do that?

```py
import numpy as np
import numpy.random


class SC(object):

    def __init__(self, key, prng=None, **kwargs):

        if prng is None:
            seed=None
            rs = np.random.RandomState(seed)
            def gen(seed):
                rs = np.random.RandomState(seed)
                while True:

                    yield rs.randint(0,255)

            self.prng = rs.randint(0, 255)

        else:
            self.prng = prng(key, **kwargs)


    def encrypt(self, plaintext):
        return self.crypting_fn(plaintext)

    def decrypt(self, ciphertext):
        return self.crypting_fn(ciphertext)

    def crypting_fn(self, text):

            crypted=bytes([b^s for b, s in zip(text, range(self.prng))])
            return crypted


message = 'hello world!'
key = 0x012345678

a = SC(key)
b = SC(key)

plaintextA = message.encode('utf-8')
ciphertext = a.encrypt(plaintextA)
plaintextB = b.decrypt(ciphertext)

print(plaintextA)
print(ciphertext)
print(plaintextB)
```

The output Is:

```
b'hello world!'
b'hdnok%qhzen*'
b'hello world!'
```

Comment: What is *wrong* with the current output? That looks reasonable. Remember, the `repr` of a `bytes` object will use printable ASCII equivalents when the values correspond to printable ASCII. You can't directly force it to use `\x` escapes for stuff that doesn't need it, and there's no good reason to do so. There're definitely other bugs (you define a function to *generate* random bytes, but don't use it, and instead just use all numbers between `0` and the single random byte you generate separately), but I'm not seeing what's wrong with the conversion to `bytes`.

Comment: Side-note: I see no reason to bother with `numpy` here; you don't use `numpy` types at all, aside from generating random, so you may as well just use the built-in `random` module (which is self-seeding, and creates an instance to use for calls by default, so you wouldn't need to explicitly create a random state at all). On 3.9+, you could replace individual calls to `randint` with bulk calls to `randbytes` (and in reality, if you were trying to generate crypto-secure keystream, you'd want to use `os.urandom` or `secrets.token_bytes`, rather than involving a PRNG).

Comment: thanks all for the comments! This is my first interaction here on stackoverflow so I'm not practical, hope to tag correctly for response. @ShadowRanger the only problem here is that for a project I have to return as an output that form and I don't do how to convert my output to that, moreover I have to use randint even though I searched and found that,as you said, secrets, random module and randbytes are way easier and safer than the randint. But also this is the cap of the code that I'm required to compute

Comment: @Logan: If you fix your use of the PRNG, you should see a lot more `\x` escapes. Right now, you don't see them because you're shifting alphabetic characters by a small amount, so they usually become other printable characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use of the PRNG is borked; instead of generating a stream of bytes, you generate a *single* byte and your keystream is just 0, 1, 2, 3... up until you hit the random byte (so when the byte is small, you don't even have enough to encrypt the entire input).

Fix your code to make `self.prng` a keystream generator, not a single random byte, and use it as such, and you'll get something that looks like what you want:

```python
import numpy as np
import numpy.random


class SC(object):
    def __init__(self, key, prng=None, **kwargs):
        if prng is None:
            def gen(seed):
                rs = np.random.RandomState(seed)
                while True:
                    yield rs.randint(0, 255)

            self.prng = gen(key)  # Seed with provided "key", not None (which seeds from system random)
        else:
            # Without knowing what prng should be, I can't be sure this line is correct
            # This is what you'd want if calling prng produced an iterator using the keystream
            self.prng = prng(key, **kwargs)

    def encrypt(self, plaintext):
        return self.crypting_fn(plaintext)

    def decrypt(self, ciphertext):
        return self.crypting_fn(ciphertext)

    def crypting_fn(self, text):
        crypted=bytes([b^s for b, s in zip(text, self.prng)])
        return crypted

message = 'hello world!'
key = 0x012345678


a = SC(key)
b = SC(key)

plaintextA = message.encode('utf-8')
ciphertext = a.encrypt(plaintextA)
plaintextB = b.decrypt(ciphertext)

print(plaintextA)
print(ciphertext)
print(plaintextB)
```

which outputs:

```
b'hello world!'
b'+\x9f\xc8\xec\xd4\\\xac\xf6\xae\xba\x9c\xeb'
b'hello world!'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVPBjpswEL37K6bqAVhRlO427SpSDt2eeumhW6mHVYsMDMENsS3biKU/n46BAMmmVecCHt48P7@HdecqJe@OR3HQyjiQzUF3wC1IzZatxHBZqANjLK@5tfD4KVTZL8xdtGEMqAosIU2FFC5NQ4t1GcMeuxi0kbvtFyUxhpubfcvNzkYbGGsY9SXKHgnCggdvpg8n7h1KosUiOv/ky1jYkt5RYvK1fzw67nCYeDHQVqJG@GYafEnWy7rW7ATWBe3VbyOkC1cx3K7X0XX0Pwi9OUl/2G1/KrLpXOK0wNpeKHwN3wUF1jjYS9UK4mgr7gbrLPVJYUZOf4acy8DRO9jGILiKfK2FRO9vroyh4P6qyT/CPrspMHaWl48DZW467cakdc3JEXx2i3QMusbIgbnHktq0lOGMZdNhPWOBS8Zc6ArNf1IuwOecS9DAe8HYA7DYZp1DGz5lPy2UykAWgwUh4bfQoZ@IZ4OiH9GlnpGEXYuQXtgBreU7JGuDCutaQatMXbwKGJlMzdXz6u3t3bv1@w/3dL04dehy@Z8CWDYvGJuM@0jdkTOhHFSBYdC48s19ENFusxkE48kpqHk6mpkeCJIlJ@eXNjJt/D@@mCLqobeAwSXsIYLj8Q8)